# How to access class members from component properties?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-meta

I need to create a mixin to set the header and meta data. For this i found vue-meta, which works great. But i'm not yet familiar with typscript and class based components.

how is the class member `pageTitle` reachable within component properties `metaInfo()`?

**sample code:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: pageTitle, // here I would like to access class member
    };
  },
})
export default class headerMixin extends Vue {
  pageTitle: string = 'Page Title'; // definition of class member
}
```

Comment: Did you try `this.pageTitle`?

Comment: I have tried it, but without success. the error message is: _Property 'pageTitle' does not exist on type 'Vue'._

Comment: This is compilation error that doesn't affect how the app works. Try to fix it with `metaInfo(this: headerMixin) {...`. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that `metaInfo` function receives component instance as context, it can be done like:

```
@Component({
  metaInfo(this: headerMixin) {
    return {
      title: this.pageTitle
    };
  },
})
export default class headerMixin extends Vue {
  pageTitle: string = 'Page Title';
}
```